# Ruby string index with escaped double quotes

Tags: ruby, parsing, html-parsing

I'm trying to split a string `email` that contains HTML content into 2 parts, one before `<div class=\"gmail_signature\">` and one after.

EDIT: Here's a sample of what's in `email`:
`My email is here<div class=\"gmail_quote\">and my signature</div>`

So I'd like to have `My email is here` and `<div class=\"gmail_quote\">and my signature</div>` separately.

Using `email.index('<div class=\"gmail_signature\">')` returns nil, because of the `\"`. The same issue happens with `gsub`.

What's the best way to deal with this?
Thanks!

Comment: show us the sample content of the string please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
email = 'aaa<div class="gmail_signature">bbb'
 => "aaa<div class=\"gmail_signature\">bbb"
email.split('<div class="gmail_signature">')
 => ["aaa", "bbb"]
```